# SAS Multilayer Format not working when uploading/downloading

Tags: formatting, sas

I'm working on PC SAS 9.1 and am working on two remote servers, as such, I'm trying to set up my parameters and formats etc; on local before uploading them to each remote server.

I've wanting to apply a Multilayered format to a proc summary.  I've got the format partially working, but something is going awry when I upload (or download) the format.

In this example below, I'm creating the MultiLabel format on the remote session.  I then create a simple dataset and apply the format.

I then carry out a Proc Summary on the data which will produce a table with the table brand field summarised firstly formatted by the model, then make, then type, resulting in a table of 8 rows.

I then download the format to the local session and perform the same dataset creation and summary.  When this is run, only the first label (Model) of the format is used in the Proc Summary, this means my dataset Summary only has 5 rows.

```
    RSubmit RemoteServer;
     Proc Format;
      Value $Brand (NotSorted MultiLabel)
       /* Model */
       'A' = 'Focus'
       'B' = 'Astra'
       'C' = 'Fiesta'
       'D' = 'Corsa'
       'E' = 'Fusion'

       /* Make */
       'A' = 'Ford'
       'B' = 'Vauxhall'
       'C' = 'Ford'
       'D' = 'Vauxhall'
       'E' = 'Ford'

       /* Type */
       'A' = 'Automobile'
       'B' = 'Automobile'
       'C' = 'Automobile'
       'D' = 'Automobile'
       'E' = 'Automobile';
     Run;
    EndRSubmit;

    RSubmit RemoteServer;
     Proc Download InCat  = Work.Formats
                   OutCat = Work.Formats;
     Run;
    EndRSubmit;

    RSubmit RemoteServer;
     Data Source;
      Do i = 1 To 5;
       If      i = 1 Then Brand = 'A';
       Else If i = 2 Then Brand = 'B';
       Else If i = 3 Then Brand = 'C';
       Else If i = 4 Then Brand = 'D';
       Else If i = 5 Then Brand = 'E';
       Volume = 1;
       Output;
      End;
      Format Brand $Brand.;
     Run;
    EndRSubmit;

    RSubmit RemoteServer;
     Proc Summary Data = Source NoPrint CompleteTypes Missing NWay;
      Class Brand / MLF PreLoadFmt Order = Data;
      Var   Volume;
      Output Out = Summary (Drop = _:)
             N() = Volume;
     Run;
    EndRSubmit;



    Data Source;
     Do i = 1 To 5;
      If      i = 1 Then Brand = 'A';
      Else If i = 2 Then Brand = 'B';
      Else If i = 3 Then Brand = 'C';
      Else If i = 4 Then Brand = 'D';
      Else If i = 5 Then Brand = 'E';
      Volume = 1;
      Output;
     End;
     Format Brand $Brand.;
    Run;

    Proc Summary Data = Source NoPrint CompleteTypes Missing NWay;
     Class Brand / MLF PreLoadFmt Order = Data;
     Var   Volume;
     Output Out = Summary (Drop = _:)
            N() = Volume;
    Run;
```

When I look at the format on each server it shows as being created correctly with the multiple labels, however it doesn't apply them.

I've tried looking on various websites, SUGI etc; but can't find anyone else who's experiencing this problem.

It feels like its something going wrong with the reading of the transferred format, because it looks to be created correctly and when the format is created on any server the table will work on that server.

I'm basically posting to see if anyone on here has come across the issue before, if they know why it may be happening, or better still if there's something that can be done to make sure the process will work as it should.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you disconnecting/connecting to the remote server(s) so much? I assume you mean REMOTESERVER1 and REMOTESERVER2? Are you sure that PROC FORMAT is correct? I realize that it is using the MULTILABLE option (which I am not familiar with), but there is only 1 VALUE statement...is that right?

Comment: Yes, the format is correct, if created on the server and then running the summary it works, its only when the format is transferred from one server to another that it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is after creating the format (on REMOTESERVER1), you then disconnect back to a LOCAL session before connecting to REMOTESERVER2. The FORMAT needs to be moved to the LOCAL session, then moved to REMOTESERVER2.

This is something that worked for me (just moving the format catalog between REMOTESERVER1, LOCAL, and REMOTESERVER2), at least the log indicated it was successfull.

```
filename RLink 'myScript' ;
options comamid=tcp remote=REMOTESERVER1;
signon REMOTESERVER1 ;
rsubmit;

 proc format;
  value $test
  'TEST'=1 ;
 run;

 Proc Download 
  InCat  = Work.Formats
  OutCat = Work.Formats;
 Run;

endrsubmit ;

/* Now back in LOCAL */

filename RLink 'myScript2' ;
options comamid = tcp remote = REMOTESERVER2 ; 
signon REMOTESERVER2 ;
rsubmit ;

 Proc Upload 
  InCat  = Work.Formats
  OutCat = Work.Formats;
 Run;

endrsubmit ;
```

Comment: Correct. When a dataset which has fields using custom formats is moved to another platform, the formats need to go with it.